# Clickable area of hyperref pushbutton extends beyond figure bounds

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, forms

The following MWE will generate a clickable rectangle:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,hyperref}

\begin{document}
\PushButton[name=button1,bordercolor=,borderwidth=0,bordersep=0]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node (rect) at (0,0) [
        rectangle,
        fill=red,  
        draw=black,
        minimum width=1cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
    ] {};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

As you can see I've set `borderwidth` and `bordersep` to `0`, and there is no margin/whitespace anywhere. Even so, the clickable area of the button extends beyond the bounds of the figure. I've tried to indicate the "hot-zone" in the following (badly drawn) picture:

[image: problem]

I can't find any other options in the hyperref manual that seem to be related.

Comment: Probably easier to use a `\rule` as the filler (the trace is shorter). To me (from `\showoutput`)  the link looks the right size at the 'TeX end': I wonder if this is a 'feature' of the viewer/PDF spec. (If you add a border, the extra 'hot' area is _outside_ the border not inside it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is indeed a viewer feature as @joseph-wright mentioned. Couldn't find anything to change this.

Comment: Do you want to execute, by chance, JavaScript code with this button? You could try `\mediabutton[jsaction={...}]{<your button face definition>}`  from the `media9` package.

Comment: I'm actually using `hyperref`'s `\PushButton` because it has support for more mouse events (enter, exit, click are the ones I'm using). Inside I have an `\animateinline` (from your `animate` package!), and the JS switches which frame is shown depending on mouse events. It's allowing me to have toggle buttons with hover states (so that's 4 pictures in total). It's pretty cool!

Comment: I see, it is quite fancy stuff you are doing. With `\mediabutton` alone you can have only 3 states (Normal, Mouse Enter, Mouse Down). So you may need to stick with `\PushButton`.